# C++ current timestamp - QDateTime vs chrono::system_clock

Tags: c++, qt, c++-chrono, qdatetime

Qt's currentMSecsSinceEpoch seems to differ from chrono::system_clock::now(). Even if I call currentMSecsSinceEpoch after system_clock::now() the timestamp returned by Qt is sometimes smaller than the stl timestamp. Why is this happening?

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <QtCore>
int main()
{
    namespace sc = std::chrono;

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        const auto stl_now = sc::system_clock::now();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(sc::microseconds{1});
        const auto qt_now = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();

        const auto duration_since_epoch = stl_now.time_since_epoch();

        std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << "1. Chrono now:           " << duration_since_epoch.count() << '\n';
        std::cout << "1. Chrono now (floored): " << sc::floor<sc::milliseconds>(duration_since_epoch).count() << '\n';
        std::cout << "2. Qt now:               " << qt_now << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1. Chrono now:           17012623315247298
1. Chrono now (floored): 1701262331524
2. Qt now:               1701262331524
 
1. Chrono now:           17012623315265318
1. Chrono now (floored): 1701262331526
2. Qt now:               1701262331526
 
1. Chrono now:           17012623315279808
1. Chrono now (floored): 1701262331527
2. Qt now:               1701262331527
 
1. Chrono now:           17012623315296035
1. Chrono now (floored): 1701262331529
2. Qt now:               1701262331529
 
1. Chrono now:           17012623315314812
1. Chrono now (floored): 1701262331531
2. Qt now:               1701262331531
 
1. Chrono now:           17012623315332218
1. Chrono now (floored): 1701262331533
2. Qt now:               1701262331532
 
1. Chrono now:           17012623315347844
1. Chrono now (floored): 1701262331534
2. Qt now:               1701262331534
 
1. Chrono now:           17012623315362278
1. Chrono now (floored): 1701262331536
2. Qt now:               1701262331535
 
1. Chrono now:           17012623315378605
1. Chrono now (floored): 1701262331537
2. Qt now:               1701262331537
 
1. Chrono now:           17012623315393145
1. Chrono now (floored): 1701262331539
2. Qt now:               1701262331539
```

Comment: Sorry, the difference is that **1ms** between the 2 calls? Did I get it right? I don't see you demonstrate that part of your question: "*Even if I call `currentMSecsSinceEpoch` after `system_clock::now()`, the timestamp returned by Qt is sometimes smaller than the stl timestamp*"

Comment: @Atmo Yes, the 1ms with taking into account the order of calls

Comment: @Atmo The demonstration of the call order is in the code at line 3 and 5

Comment: @Atmo In the second iteration Qt meassures 1701255021478 when chrono meassures 1701255021479. The Qt value is smaller even though it got called after chrono. So it should be greater. I checked it in debug and release mode.

Comment: the implementation looks a little odd https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5ef5f2f1b9d90264df02277884e5e18f8c1fc783/src/corelib/time/qdatetime.cpp#L5303 it might not be surprising that it has rounding errors

Comment: I suggest you do that very same test with a `steady_clock` instead of `system_clock`, just to be sure.

Comment: @Atmo `steady_clock` does not measure wall time since 1970, so it cant be compared with currentMSecsSinceEpoch.

Comment: My point is: let's imagine the issue disappears when you use a `steady_clock`, would that perhaps provide a clue towards something?

Comment: No clue needed : std::chrono::system_clock is not a monotonic increasing clock (only use it for wall clock time) for anything else use std::chrono::steady_clock. std::chrono::system_clock is even allowed to go backward in time (e.g. when your system clock ran faster then real time, and your PC synchronized with a time server) but for similar reasons it might also jump ahead in time

Comment: @PepijnKramer I know that, but because `std::chrono::system_clock` is allowed to go back in time, it does not necessarily means this is what is happening here. Especially, it happened twice in the span of 15ms between the first and the last times measured in the question; it was 5 discrepancies over 15ms in the original version of it. Would this not rule out things like synchronization? I do not know how often a PC synchronizes its time but I doubt it is that often. And if it indeed rules it out, what else causes a `system_clock` to go back in time? And why does it seem to only go 1 way?

Comment: It strange indeed, but will it be a problem in practice? I would write my code to use one source of time truth anyway (single source of data principle)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Windows:

Qt calls [GetSystemTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtime) whereas chrono uses [GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtimepreciseasfiletime). GetSystemTime has a resolution / precision of milliseconds as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-systemtime). GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime uses the highest precision possible which is <1µs, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtimepreciseasfiletime).

The unexpected behaviour could be explained by the fact that under the hood two different system calls are used to get the wall clock time.

Comment: If you think you have understood what is going on, could you perhaps give more explanation about the mechanism? In your question, you call the high precision clock (`stl_now`) that you round **down**, then the less precise one (`qt_now`), meaning. If the mechanism at play was just a matter of precision, surely a round down means you get the previous ms, not the next one as your question suggests.

Comment: Continued to my previous comment: what the question says is 1 of the loops calculated `stl_now = 17012623315332218` and **only after it did**, it calculated  `qt_now = 1701262331532`. My point above is: if the issue was only about the precision of clocks, we should always have `floor(stl_now) <= qt_now`, and the above answer does not address that.

Comment: @Atmo Since I am calling Chrono (GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime) first and Qt (GetSystemTime) "later" rounding instead of flooring would only increase the chrono timestamps (on average). The floored value is already >= Qt timestamp in most of the cases.

Comment: @Atmo so your point is that the difference is the result of calling two different syscalls and this should be the conclusion?

Comment: Again, my point is: if all that was happening was precision/rounding, you should only see `floor(stl_now) <= qt_now` (if I am wrong in my reasoning, please do tell me where). Yet, your question is about seeing `qt_now < floor(stl_now)`.

Comment: @Atmo Could you clarify your point a bit more? floor(stl_now) <= qt_now is indeed the expected behaviour and the confusion came from why it does not hold true all the time. But since there are two different system calls involved it totally makes sense. So I would edit the summary of my answer, to only mention the different system calls and remove the part about precision

Comment: Maybe the behavior can be explained by the different systems used, although I do not see anything in what you posted that proves the results are not guaranteed to be the same, within the precision of each. All the contrary in fact: `GetSystemTime` "*retrieves the current system date and time in [...] UTC format*" while `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` "*retrieves the current system date and time with the highest possible level [...] in UTC format*" (quotes from the microsoft website) -> No difference to be expected there.

Comment: Even if there was a difference and it was documented elsewhere, at the very least, the sentence "*So the unexpected behaviour can be explained **by the difference in precision** of the two system calls.*" is off the mark. The **difference in precision** is the one thing that cannot explain the behavior you experience.

Comment: @Atmo the difference in precision might not explain it by itself, but what it implies may be the real explanation.  Those system calls may be using two completely different clocks, and those clocks may be unequal to a degree that can be seen.  I haven't looked at the documentation, but I'm guessing neither function tells you exactly what it's using as a time source.